# how can I configure availability sets in azure?

Tags: azure

I am not very familiar with this in azure.

I created one centos vm, I created an availability set, in order to enable auto scaling I need to create another VM in the same availability set.

so I will create another vm, with the same image.

So, these 2 vms will replicate each other? if I install something in one VM, will it be replicated automatically to the other vm?, should I use only one of the vms as the starter point to install and configure things?

or should I do everything manually on each VM? Example, if I open port 80 in one I should do it in another?, if I install magento in one, I should install it in the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure will not replicate your VMs automatically. There are some manual steps involved:

1. You need to prepare one VM as a starter point.
2. Then you manually clone VMs up to a maximum number that you will need.
3. Make sure all they are in the same availability set.
4. Set up auto scaling

Now Azure will scale automatically by turning some of your VMs on and off. When VM is turned off, you will only incur storage costs for it. And storage in Azure is almost free.

Comment: so I prepare one vm with everything, like mysql, apache, and all needed software, once I am sure everything is fine I clone it and put it in the same availability set, and thats it?, if I later need to make another config change, like install a new package or software, lets says wordpress, then I need to install it in both servers correct:?,  by the way, how can I clone a VM?  thanks

Comment: You can either make additional changes to both servers or to only one and then again clone it. I think this will help you: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/

Comment: This is has been a good answer, but I still have a query. I followed the link and still not clear and it is about linux. I have exactly the same system I want to scale. I have my app installed in a windows server and I want  scale set the same copy. Can you give me any direct hints or link . Regards.

Comment: @soulemanemoumie: OPs question was about CentOS Linux VM. I think you need to post a new question regarding your issue and describe there what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: How to configure availability set

I created a post covering this on [How to guard your application from azure outages](http://www.siemerforhire.com/post/175/how-to-guard-your-application-from-azure-outages)

- Use the quick create to stand up a VM of your choice
- Once the instance is running click on the configure tab and create a new availability set
- Click save
- Saving will force a shut down, reconfigure, startup process
- Once the VM comes back online you can create a 2nd VM
- Using the create from gallery option, click through all the create screens until you get to the configure virtual machine screen (screen 4 at the moment)
- Select the cloud service that was created with your first VM (availability sets require the VM's to run in the same cloud service)
- Then select the availability set you created for the first VM
- Finish the creation of your second VM
- You can now see the linked VM's in the same availability set by clicking on the configure tab for any VM in the availability set you created.  It will list all VMs in a given availability set inside the details of the VM